# Detect if there is voice in a wav file

Tags: audio, naudio, voice-recognition

I am being assigned a task that I need to identify if there is a talking voice in a wav file of 20 to 30 second long or just silence (I guess silence is considered when its decibel is less than 20). The result should be as simple as this: true if there is voice, false if its just silence. The wav file has the following:

- 8,000 Hz sample rate
- 16 bits per sample
- 1 channel

So far I've been experimenting the NAudio package but not sure what to do to achieve the goal. Can anyone shed a light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at these 2 videos. When printing the waveforms, it gives you values of when there is audio. You should be able to observe and pick what you need.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnFoVuOVrUQ   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP2MhB2KQe0

Comment: I have come up with this solution using NAudio library and it works quite well with my expectation. Here it is: 1) I read the wave file into float array buffers of size of 8,000 which is equal to 1 second 2) Within each float array buffer, I split it into smaller blocks, says 200 and calculate the average peak using RMS (root mean square) method 3) I then convert to decibel using this equation `decibel = 20 * Math.Log10(rms)` and compare with the conversation decibel threshold to determine if there is voice in the wave file or not.

Answer (score 0):

the approach, where you can use VAD(voice activity detector) for finding speech in wav file

```
SAMPLING_RATE = 8000

import torch
torch.set_num_threads(1)


# download example
torch.hub.download_url_to_file('https://models.silero.ai/vad_models/en.wav', 'en_example.wav')

USE_ONNX = False # change this to True if you want to test onnx model
if USE_ONNX:
    !pip install -q onnxruntime
  
model, utils = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-vad',
                              model='silero_vad',
                              force_reload=True,
                              onnx=USE_ONNX)

(get_speech_timestamps,
 save_audio,
 read_audio,
 VADIterator,
 collect_chunks) = utils

wav = read_audio('en_example.wav', sampling_rate=SAMPLING_RATE)

# get speech timestamps from full audio file
speech_timestamps = get_speech_timestamps(wav, model, sampling_rate=SAMPLING_RATE)
print(speech_timestamps)
```